# Can't access a local site site on LAN

Tags: web-server, lighttpd

I have lighttpd setup on a machine (say ip is 10.107.105.13) with following details.

```
inet addr : 10.107.105.13
Bcast : 10.107.111.255
Mask : 255.255.240.0
```

I can access my site on this computer by using `firefox http://localhost/index.html`.

Now I am trying to access this site from another computer with following details

```
inet addr : 10.14.42.7
Bcast : 10.14.42.255
Mask : 255.255.255.0
```

But it says 'access denied'.

nmap 10.107.105.13 gives the following output.

```
PORT     STATE SERVICE
22/tcp   open  ssh
80/tcp   open  http
1234/tcp open  hotline
3306/tcp open  mysql
9418/tcp open  git
```

Following is the output of `iptables -L -n -v` on 10.107.105.13

```
 141 11207 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:80 
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:80
```

FORWARD and OUTPUT section empty.

What is wrong with all this?

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps lighttp is configured to only listen on the localhost IP address (127.0.0.1) while you need it to listen on all of them (typically 0.0.0.0).

Answer (score 1):

The problem was with proxy authentication step. I had to add `10.0.0.0/8` in no-proxy variables in my browser and everything worked smoothly.

Comment: Now that you have your solution, you should mark this as the answer (the checkmark to the left)

Comment: I have to wait for 2 days to accept my own answer. StackOverflow policy.

Answer (score 0):

Enable prerouting in you iptables because your both machine's subnet masks are different.